# Find distribution of $X$

Tags: probability-distributions, conditional-probability

If there are random variables $X$ and $N$ which satisfies
$$N\sim poisson(\lambda) \\ X\mid N\sim B(N, p)$$
$N$ is a poisson distribution with expectation $\lambda$ and $X$ given $N$ is a binomial distribution with N trials and p success probability.

I already get if $X, Y$ are poisson distribution with expectations $\lambda p$ and $\lambda(1- p), N= X+ Y$ then it satisfies above conditions.

But, I cannot explain to myself why it has to be like that.

Could I find out distribution of $X$ and reasonable explanation for why is it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability mass function of $X$ can be written as
$$
P(X=k) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty}P(X=k|N=i)P(N=i)
$$
You said, $X|N$ is a binomial with parameter $N$ and $p$, therefore for any non-negative integer $k$

$$
P(X=k) = \sum_{i=k}^{\infty} {i\choose k} p^{k}(1-p)^{i-k} \exp(-\lambda)\frac{\lambda^i}{i!} $$
$$= \exp(-\lambda p)\frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!}\sum_{i=k}^{\infty}\exp(-\lambda(1-p))\frac{(\lambda(1-p))^{i-k}}{(i-k)!}.
$$
Now write $j=i-k$ and you will see that the last sum is $1$ and thus

$$
P(X=k) =\exp(-\lambda p)\frac{(\lambda p)^k}{k!}
$$
for $k=0,1,\ldots$.

Comment: I got it except why $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}$ becomes $\sum_{i=k}^{\infty}$.

Could you explain why?

Comment: Yes, can $X$ takes a value less than $k$ if it is given that $N=i$? (You said $X|N$ is binomial $(N,p)$)